# How to get negative samples for reccomender system

Tags: reinforcement-learning, recommender-system

In a recommendation system that is based on user preferences and item features (rather than a collaborative filtering approach), how might training be done if only positive samples can be found? For example, it is much easier to record when a user interacts with an item and mark it as a positive interaction, but getting "negative" interactions is either very rare (going out of their way to hide or remove a result) or nonexistant. How can a system be built that accounts for this?
One option is simply keeping track of everything served to the user, and marking everything they do not interact with as negative, but I believe this would be very noisy, as it's possible they simply did not want it at the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking negative training examples from what the user explicitly did not interact with is a right approach. This is analogous to how word2vec with negative sampling does things. Do make sure the chosen negatives items are ones the user had a chance to explicitly interact/view & not an item that would have been shown on page 20+, so pedantic tracking the user journey helps.

In large enough volumes, training with negative examples (even if some of them are bad) yields better results. The trick is picking the right positive to negative proportions.

If concerned about noise of the negative signal you could cluster users into personas & random sample examples (with probability corresponding to their natural occurrence frequency) from the cluster the user belongs to. To diminish the effects of incorrectly sampling negative items the user is truly interested but not at that time, you should model these temporal & task oriented behaviours as features themselves for learning to pickup. Ie: time of day item was chosen, similarity between other positive/negative items chosen, time difference between choices, etc.